# In what format should I write a vocabulary with synonyms into a file?

Tags: c, file-io, format

Iv'e been given a mission on my homework on c language - file I/O. The programm should accept two files, one of them should be a text(*.txt) with a sentence in it, and the other file should contain some words, and for each word it will contain unknown number of synonym.The programm should write a new sentence to the text file, while replacing all of the posiible words with a synonym word from the vocabulary file. What, in your opinion, will be the best format to the vocabulary file(txt or other)? in what way should I insert the data(if it's a txt, should it like a word and then on the same line all of the synonym?)? and how do I need to handle with the file in the program?

Comment: good luck on your mission soldier! HOORAH

Answer (score 2):

> *"The program should write a new sentence to the text file, while replacing all of the possible words with a synonym word from the vocabulary file... What, in your opinion, will be the best format to the vocabulary file(txt or other)?"*

Format of the file doesn't really matter that much. Your program will most likely load its contents to the memory (some data structure) and what really matters is how you're going to use these synonyms afterwards.

> "*...should it like a word and then on the same line all of the synonym?*"

That sounds reasonable if your program will load it with *push* approach, i.e. process the file line by line. You will most likely need a data structure to allow you retrieve list of synonyms when given a word, thus:

```
word1 synonym1 synonym2 ... synonymN
word2 synonym1 synonym2 ... synonymN
...
wordM synonym1 synonym2 ... synonymN
```

will do just fine. Now go and try to write some codes :)